# How to get all deleted sites using Microsoft API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Is there a way to get a list of all deleted sites in sharePoint using Microsoft graph API? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for below deleted sites via API?

[image]

If so, you can have a try below method.

- There is a hidden list called "DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGA" in the admin site. It stores a cached copy of aggregated site collections data from all contentDB.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/lists`

[image]

- Get items and use filter to get all deleted sites

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/lists/90403211-a51b-4a2b-8e83-a569011b63f7/items?$expand=fields&$filter=State eq '9' or State eq '6'`

BR